# MVC 4 site 508 compliant

Tags: asp.net-mvc, testing, asp.net-mvc-4, section508

I have spent a lot of time researching this, but perhaps someone point me in the right direction.  In need of building an MVC 4 website in which it is 508 Compliant.  I did some 508 compliance testing and tag inserts 3 years ago, but I really want to look at doing this again.   What are other people using?  What tags to look for?   What Testing Tools? Any free testing tools?

Are AJAX and jQuery and Javascript compliant, I seem to find answers like "it depends"  Thus in need of this compliance as the company wants to sell product to the government and needs to be compliant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am going to take a stab at your question, but I think you need to flesh out your question.

> What are other people using? What tags to look for?

Section 508 is more-or-less UI-focused rather than backend. For example, you can walk around the block 5 times to develop/display a form, but as long as each `<input>` has a `<label>` that is all that matters. You may want to [review the standards for compliance](http://section508.gov/index.cfm?fuseAction=stdsdoc#Web). That is a link to the standards for websites. But a lot of agencies use the software application standards *AND* the website standards for sites that are considered applications. Documentation provided with your system must be compliant which is covered under 1194.41, which references 1194.22.

> Testing tools

There are various tools, but one of the best is [WAVE](http://wave.webaim.org/).

> Are AJAX and jQuery and Javascript compliant, I seem to find answers like "it depends" Thus in need of this compliance as the company wants to sell product to the government and needs to be compliant.

Since there is so many ways to to construct things, the answer is kind of "it depends." My answer on [modal dialogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298525/setting-focus-of-a-screen-reader-on-a-modal-alert-in-ember/11299878#11299878) and [others in accessibility](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:1276124+[accessibility]) may help more. The [jQuery page](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/accessibility) has a tag for accessible plug-ins. There is also a [jQuery Accessibility Google group](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-a11y/) that may be a good resource.

Comment: That is nicely answered, exactly what I needed.  Thanks Ryan!

Comment: You are welcome. I made a few tweaks to my answer, you may want to review them.

Comment: Hey, wondering about keyboard shortcuts.   (A UI/UX designer is using twitter bootstrap css stuff )  So how are menu's and keyboards tied in to be accessible and the keyboard shortcuts?   Thanks again

Comment: Asking another question would be best, since this is off topic to your question. You may want to examine my answers here  on SO, or questions in the accessibility tag, before asking your question to make sure it wasn't asked previously.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11655214/are-keyboard-shortcuts-mandatory-for-508-compliance    thanks Ryan