# Need WCAG2.0 testing tool for a ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, accessibility, wcag

We are developing a ASP.NET website with VS2012. Need to pass WCAG2.0 guidelines. The Check Accessibility checklist in VS2012 doesn't match one-to-one with the guidelines.

Anyone has any pointers to any tools specific to WCAG2.0 guideline checklist?

Comment: Please search the site before posting, there are numerous threads on this, here is an answer that I wrote: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424355/mvc-4-site-508-compliant/11439747#11439747

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [HTML Code Sniffer](http://squizlabs.github.io/HTML_CodeSniffer/), a browser bookmarklet that runs javascript assertions on a page, that map to WCAG2A, AA, AAA or section 508.

HTML Code Sniffer also has a phantomjs [command line runner](https://github.com/squizlabs/HTML_CodeSniffer/blob/master/PhantomJS/HTMLCS_Run.js) that you could try integrating into a ASP.NET test suite.

The syntax looks like this: `phantomjs HTMLCS_Run.js URL standard`" where standards are `"WCAG2A", "WCAG2AA", "WCAG2AAA"`. It outputs a pipe delimited list of errors.